# Terraform - Failed to marshal plan to json: error marshaling prior state - azurerm_storage_account

Tags: terraform, azure-rm

I'm fairly new to terraform, and am encountering a problem running a plan command in an Azure devops pipeline that I don't seem to be able to reproduce locally. The error message is

"Failed to marshal plan to json: error marshaling prior state: schema version 3 for azurerm_storage_account.sta in state does not match version 4 from the provider."

The first thing that puzzles me is that the problem is being reported at the azurerm_storage_account level, as opposed to a problem with the top level azurerm provider.

I'm running version 1.3.9 of terraform. Is this that I need to limit the provider version, so that it doesn't use the latest version automatically? I don't understand why it wouldn't be doing the same thing on my local. The lock.hcl file is under source control so I would expect this to also be used in the devops pipeline.

I am using the "target" flag. Is this potentially a reason they recommend against using it.

Comment: Please provide the TF code allowing for reproduction of the issue.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the problem locally myself and the error only occurs running on a Azure Devops pipeline. It's quite a large project too. My gut feel is that it's related to a update to the provider (as the pipeline has run successfully in the past) but am not familiar enough with Terraform to investigate further or understand why running locally might work differently.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the pipeline was built with "terraform init -upgrade", which is still how it should be. However the repeated use of targeting might have messed things up a bit as only part of the full solution would be updated/rebuilt.

Workaround was to update the pipeline to remove the "-upgrade" flag temporarily, and that got things working again. Plan is to consider a clean slate refresh at some later point and enforce less use of targeting after that.